# How to separate users (models) by admins and customers on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to separate users of my Django app in two classes :
- **Admin** (users that use Django admin) - inherit from `AbstractUser`
- **User** (customers users) - inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`

I want to separate this two kinds of users because all fields of `AbstractUser` (`is_staff`, `is_superuser`, `groups`, `permissions`) are useless for my customer users and for permissions and group, I just want to implement something different. That why, I want to use `AbstractBaseUser`.

But for django admin users, `AbstractUser` class, it's just perfect and particularly with permissions feature.

```python
class Admin(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):
    pass
```

But now, is there a way to precise the User model used `Admin` for the django admin only?
And use the `Customer` model for the rest of my apps.

Did I have to implement this from scratch :

```python
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Admin(MyUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Customer(MyUser):
    # specific fields
    pass
```

With this implementation, if I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `User`, permissions will not work because `User` has no `permissions`, `is_superuser` and `is_staff` fields.

And if a set it to `Admin`, I will not be able to authenticate `Customers` with `django.contrib.auth`.

So guys do you have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Having two separate models will definitely break either `contrib.auth` or `contrib.admin`, no matter if your `request.user` contains `User` or `Admin`. Are there any objective reasons against having one base `User` model with, say, two "profile" `OneToOne` fields? If some fields are useless for some group of your users, just don't use them, you're not obligated to do it after all. Or you're worried about performance issues?

Comment: TY for reply man. As I said : "I want to separate this two kinds of users because all fields of `AbstractUser` (`is_staff`, `is_superuser`, `groups`, `permissions`) are useless for my customer users and for permissions and group, I just want to implement something different. That why, I want to use `AbstractBaseUser`." If customer have two kind of permissions and groups, it gonna be a mess. I'm quite new on Django and maybe I'm wrong and it's not possible. I just want something efficient and clean.

Comment: Well, the very point is that your users don't have to have two sets of permissions. The only permissions "container" is in the `User` model. If your user is an admin, he has the `is_staff` set and the appropriate permissions assigned. If he's a customer, then `is_staff` is `False` and his permissions are just different (you can, and probably will want to, set up some permissions for different types of customers), or maybe empty. This gives you an ability to make, for example, a customer an admin, and vice versa. Sorry, comments have the length limit, maybe I should put together an answer :).

Comment: If you have found a solution to this, could you please share it here?

Answer (score 7):

The way Django offers to you seems to be much more flexible and future-adapted.

1. You have a built-in `User` model, which you can override. Anyway, that model has permissions, groups, etc.
2. If you need different field sets for different kinds of users, you [create a `OneToOne` profile models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).
3. The separation point between your admins (actually, staff users) and regular customers is a `User.is_staff` attribute.

This way you gain a bunch of cool stuff (compared to two completely different user models):

- **Everything works out of the box**: `contrib.auth` and `contrib.admin` modules.
- **Easy-customisable separation point**: just override the [`admin_site.has_permission()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L168) and here you go.
- You have the ability (but not obligation) to create users which are **either customers and admins**.
- You can assign **groups and permissions** (different from your admins' ones) to your customers. Even you don't need it now, who knows.

As for drawbacks. The only one you've pointed out so far: your customers will be having (unused for now) permissions. Well, as they (as well as groups) are just separate tables, your customer data will have no performance of storage overhead.

That is to say, the overhead is negligeable compared to the benefits. I'd strongly recommend staying with Django's default `User` model and extending it if necessary.

Comment: You didn't read carefully my question, my customers will have permissions and groups but different of `django.contrib.auth` provides. What I want to do is currently impossible then I will create a `User` class that inherit from `PermissionsMixin` and `AbstractBaseUser` and use different names to store groups and permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I definitely should have read the question more carefully. At the first (and some consecutive) glance I thought you just don't want to have that fields being around. The only way I imagine is to implement your custom groups and permissions as fields of a separate `Customer` "profile" model linked to the `User` class. So for your customer views you will be checking something like `request.user.customer.groups`.

Comment: profile or inheritance way, not decided yet, i'm gonna think about it

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro after 3 years you come back and reply comment here ;) ? Have you decided yet ? I want to know as well, cos i am working on it at this moment